# Выдвигающееся боковое меню на CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css3, меню

Выдвигающееся боковое меню на CSS3: http://stylesystem.ru/test

```css
#JampPanel:hover {
  margin-right: -20px;
}

#JampPanel,
#JampPanel .container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px solid #FE2323;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  top: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #626262;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #626262;
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #626262;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #626262;
}

#JampPanel {
  opacity: 0.86;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1200;
  height: 190px;
  top: 200px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -202px;
  background: #F0F0F0 url(http://uploads.ru/i/S/z/t/Sztn3.png) 4px 2px no-repeat;
  transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  width: 230px;
}

#JampPanel .container {
  padding: 12px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -1px 0 0 30px;
}

#Zaslonyalka {
  /*прикрывает область тени на стыке уха с container*/
  position: absolute;
  height: 190px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -18px;
}
```

```html
<!-- JampPanel-->

<div id=JampPanel>
  <div class=container>
    <div id=Zaslonyalka></div>
    Ваш контент
  </div>
</div>
<!--End//JampPanel-->
```

Задачи следующие (желательно без использования Java Script):
-окно выезжает, но не закрывается
-в окне есть кнопка "Закрыть"
По возможности:
-окно можно свободно перетащить в любое место

Comment: можно переделать на :focus , интересные эффекты получатся , можно прикрутить кучу разных эффектов